# Getting unnecessary data as output with CMD Invoke-AzVMRunCommand

Tags: powershell

I am trying to Get-PSDrive details from a vm by using Invoke-AzVMRunCommand

```
$managedDisks = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroupName -VMName vmname -CommandId RunPowerShellScript -ScriptPath D:\Sathiya\Poweshell\PSDrive\cmd1.ps1
```

Script in cmd1.ps1

```
$managedDisks = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroupName -VMName vmname -CommandId RunPowerShellScript -ScriptPath D:\Sathiya\Poweshell\PSDrive\cmd1.ps1
```

OUTPUT what I got :

[image]

Expected output :

[image]

When I run the same script in vm Run Command output is

[image]

This is perfect

Why unnecessary data throwing when I run through `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first command use this instead:

```
$managedDisks = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName ResourceGroupName -VMName vmname -CommandId RunPowerShellScript -ScriptPath D:\Sathiya\Poweshell\PSDrive\cmd1.ps1
$managedDisks.value[0].message
```